# R split text on empty line

Tags: r

I have a very long file that looks like this :

```
"Ach! Hans, Run!" 
2RRGG
Enchantment
At the beginning of your upkeep, you may say "Ach! Hans, run! It's the . . ." and name a creature card. If you do, search your library for the named card, put it into play, then shuffle your library. That creature has haste. Remove it from the game at end of turn.
UNH-R

A Display of My Dark Power
Scheme
When you set this scheme in motion, until your next turn, whenever a player taps a land for mana, that player adds one mana to his or her mana pool of any type that land produced.
ARC-C

AErathi Berserker
2RRR
Creature -- Human Berserker
2/4
Rampage 3 (Whenever this creature becomes blocked, it gets +3/+3 until end of turn for each creature blocking it beyond the first.)
LE-U

AEther Adept
1UU
Creature -- Human Wizard
2/2
When AEther Adept enters the battlefield, return target creature to its owner's hand.
M11-C, M12-C, DDM-C

...
```

I'd like to load this file into a data.frame or vector "oracle", split by each empty line(actually a space and a newline) so that

```
oracle[1]
```

gives output like

```
"Ach! Hans, Run!" 2RRGG Enchantment At the beginning of your upkeep, you may say "Ach! Hans, run! It's the . . ." and name a creature card. If you do, search your library for the named card, put it into play, then shuffle your library. That creature has haste. Remove it from the game at end of turn. UNH-R
```

I've tried code like

```
oracle <- read.table(file = "All Sets.txt", quote = "", sep="\n")
```

as well as scan(), but

```
oracle[1]
```

gives very long, undesired output.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it ever the case that a single entry has a `\n` in the middle? None of your example does, so `Filter(nzchar, readLines("foo.txt"))` might suffice (and give your desired output). (If mid-line `\n` might happen, please update your sample to reflect it.)

Comment: no midline \n but there are \n at the end of each line, as reflected in the example, and I am looking to split by empty line not by \n

Comment: How does the code in my first comment fail your requirements?

Comment: The `read.table` command you show does work. It gives you a one column data.frame of n rows. So to extract first row, do oracle[1,]. You can transform it `vec<-as.vector(oracle[,1])`. `vec[1]` gives the first line.Note: `oracle[1]` is giving you all rows in the first column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, based on your edited question:

```
oracle <- readLines("BenYoung2.txt")
nvec <- length(oracle)
breaks <- which(! nzchar(oracle))
nbreaks <- length(breaks)
if (breaks[nbreaks] < nvec) {
  breaks <- c(breaks, nvec + 1L)
  nbreaks <- nbreaks + 1L
}
if (nbreaks > 0L) {
  oracle <- mapply(function(a,b) paste(oracle[a:b], collapse = " "),
                   c(1L, 1L + breaks[-nbreaks]),
                   breaks - 1L)
}


oracle[1]
# [1] "\"Ach! Hans, Run!\"  2RRGG Enchantment At the beginning of your upkeep, you may say \"Ach! Hans, run! It's the . . .\" and name a creature card. If you do, search your library for the named card, put it into play, then shuffle your library. That creature has haste. Remove it from the game at end of turn. UNH-R"
```

Edit: though this works fine if you always have truly-empty lines as breaks, you can use this line instead to use lines with white-space only:

```
breaks <- which(grepl("^[[:space:]]*$", oracle))
```

This gives the same results when the lines are truly empty.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's easiest to build a new variable that says which group the line belongs in, then group by that and call `paste`. In base R:

```
lines <- readLines(textConnection(txt))

i <- cumsum(lines == '')

by(lines, i, paste, collapse='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward way to do that is first splitting on a line break (i.e. `\n`), then throwing away empty lines.

```
text = "line1

line2
line3
"

split1 = unlist(strsplit(text, "\n"))
filter = split1[split1 != ""]
# [1] "line1" "line2" "line3"
```

Comment: sorry this doesn't work. I'm not looking to split by newline. As I wrote in the OP, I'm looking to split by empty line. I also gave example feedback, which this does not produce.