# Handling blocked data in R

Tags: r, text, scanf

I have a big text file (located here https://www.dropbox.com/s/k2jqbpgtxw7d66m/test.txt?dl=0) on soil data from WISE soil database which is a bit messy and I need to extract some information out of it.

The text file is organised in some sort of groups which are separated by an empty line and each group follows the same structure as shown in the image below:

```
*WI_CLAF001  WISE        L       150 WISE DATABASE, SOIL AF001
@SITE        COUNTRY          LAT     LONG SCS Family
 -99         Afganistan    34.500   69.167 Luvic Calcisol (CLl)
@ SCOM  SALB  SLU1  SLDR  SLRO  SLNF  SLPF  SMHB  SMPX  SMKE
    BN  0.13  9.60  0.60 75.00  1.00  1.00 SA001 SA001 SA001
@  SLB  SLMH  SLLL  SDUL  SSAT  SRGF  SSKS  SBDM  SLOC  SLCL  SLSI  SLCF  SLNI  SLHW  SLHB  SCEC  SADC
    15     - 0.129 0.283 0.459  1.00  1.56  1.35  0.76 20.00 40.00 20.00  0.06  7.90 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0
    60     - 0.184 0.327 0.466  0.47  0.69  1.37  0.23 35.00 55.00 -99.0  0.03  7.90 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0
   150     - 0.178 0.311 0.461  0.12  0.87  1.39  0.09 35.00 55.00 -99.0  0.03  7.90 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0
@  SLB  SLPX  SLPT  SLPO CACO3  SLAL  SLFE  SLMN  SLBS  SLPA  SLPB  SLKE  SLMG  SLNA  SLSU  SLEC  SLCA
    15 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0   9.3 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0   0.4 -99.0
    60 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0  17.7 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0   0.3 -99.0
   150 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0  18.2 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0   0.3 -99.0

*WI_FLAF002  WISE        L       170 WISE DATABASE, SOIL AF002
@SITE        COUNTRY          LAT     LONG SCS Family
 -99         Afganistan    34.500   69.000 Calcaric Fluvisol (FLc)
@ SCOM  SALB  SLU1  SLDR  SLRO  SLNF  SLPF  SMHB  SMPX  SMKE
    BN  0.13  9.60  0.25 75.00  1.00  1.00 SA001 SA001 SA001
@  SLB  SLMH  SLLL  SDUL  SSAT  SRGF  SSKS  SBDM  SLOC  SLCL  SLSI  SLCF  SLNI  SLHW  SLHB  SCEC  SADC
    20     - 0.136 0.312 0.477  0.82  1.17  1.29  1.28 20.00 40.00 -99.0  0.09  8.50 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0
    60     - 0.110 0.235 0.502  0.45  4.84  1.24  0.60 20.00 65.00 -99.0  0.06  8.60 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0
   110     - 0.210 0.344 0.472  0.18  0.53  1.35  0.39 35.00 55.00 -99.0  0.06  8.50 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0
   170     - 0.115 0.268 0.441  0.06  1.68  1.41  0.27 20.00 40.00 -99.0  0.03  8.80 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0
@  SLB  SLPX  SLPT  SLPO CACO3  SLAL  SLFE  SLMN  SLBS  SLPA  SLPB  SLKE  SLMG  SLNA  SLSU  SLEC  SLCA
    20 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0  19.1 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0   0.4 -99.0
    60 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0  19.2 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0   0.3 -99.0
   110 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0  20.3 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0   0.3 -99.0
   170 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0  24.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0   0.3 -99.0

*WI_FLAF003  WISE        L       110 WISE DATABASE, SOIL AF003
@SITE        COUNTRY          LAT     LONG SCS Family
 -99         Afganistan    34.500   69.167 Calcaric Fluvisol (FLc)
@ SCOM  SALB  SLU1  SLDR  SLRO  SLNF  SLPF  SMHB  SMPX  SMKE
    BN  0.13  9.60  0.05 75.00  1.00  1.00 SA001 SA001 SA001
@  SLB  SLMH  SLLL  SDUL  SSAT  SRGF  SSKS  SBDM  SLOC  SLCL  SLSI  SLCF  SLNI  SLHW  SLHB  SCEC  SADC
    20     A 0.106 0.276 0.453  0.82  1.66  1.37  0.59 20.00 40.00 -99.0  0.07  8.80 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0
    50    Bg 0.135 0.238 0.404  0.50  2.14  1.49  0.24 10.00 25.00 -99.0  0.04  9.20 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0
   110    Cg 0.081 0.214 0.428  0.20  3.86  1.46 -99.0 25.00 15.00 -99.0 -99.0  8.90 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0
@  SLB  SLPX  SLPT  SLPO CACO3  SLAL  SLFE  SLMN  SLBS  SLPA  SLPB  SLKE  SLMG  SLNA  SLSU  SLEC  SLCA
    20 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0  16.9 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0   1.9 -99.0
    50 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0  13.8 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0   0.6 -99.0
   110 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0  19.6 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0 -99.0   0.4 -99.0
```

Row 1: *WI_... has some details. Not useful to me

ROW 2: has headings such as country name, lat, long

ROW 3: contains data for those headings

Row 4: another set of headings

Row 5: contains data for headings in Row 4

Row 6: contains headings

Row 7:9: contains data for Row 6

Row 10: is a continuation of headings of Row 6

Row 11:13: contains data for row 10

The issue is if you move to some other group of data (a different country), the number of lines from row 6 change

I am trying to do two things for each group:

1) Have a separate dataframe for Row 2 till Row 5 which should look like:

```
  COUNTRY   LAT LONG SCS Family SCOM SALB SLU1 SLDR SLRO SLNF SLPF SMHB SMPX SMKE 
  Afghanistan
  Afghanistan
  Afghanistan
  .
  .
  .
  Argentina
  Argentina
  Argentina
  .
  .
  .
```

2) Separate dataframe for row 6 till row N

```
  COUNTRY     LAT       LONG    SLB  SLMH  SLLL  SDUL  SSAT  SRGF  SSKS  SBDM  SLOC  SLCL  SLSI  SLCF  SLNI  SLHW  SLHB  SCEC  SADC  SLPX  SLPT  SLPO CACO3  SLAL  SLFE  SLMN  SLBS  SLPA  SLPB  SLKE  SLMG  SLNA  SLSU  SLEC  SLCA
  Afganistan  34.500   69.167   15
  Afganistan  34.500   69.167   60
  Afganistan  34.500   69.167   150
```

I haven't handled such type of data before but here's some of my logic how would I achieve this:

For the 1) part, I could read the data:

```
  dat <- readLines("dat.txt")
```

remove the rows that has "WISE" in it. This is the redundant row
then split the data into list by using the empty space
[R split text on empty line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38958597/r-split-text-on-empty-line)

For each element (group) of the list: take row 2 - 5 and convert into my desired format.

Not sure what should I do for row 6 onwards for the second part of the question.

I would appreciate some help in this. Thank you very much.

Comment: For part 2 use grep to identify lines starting with `"@SITE"`, add 1, and read those lines with `read.table( ,nrows=1,header=TRUE)`. Then `cbind` that result to ones read from single lines that immediately follow `"@ SCOM". For part 3: use read.table with nrows=3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the text I inserted in place of your picture to a named character variable `txt`, then:

```
tL <- readLines(textConnection(txt))
Site_lines=grep("@SITE",tL)
Site_lines
#[1]  2 16 32
lapply( Site_lines , function(L) read.table(text= tL, header=TRUE, skip=L-1, nrow=1) )
#-----------------------
[[1]]
        X.SITE COUNTRY    LAT  LONG      SCS Family
-99 Afganistan    34.5 69.167 Luvic Calcisol  (CLl)

[[2]]
        X.SITE COUNTRY LAT     LONG      SCS Family
-99 Afganistan    34.5  69 Calcaric Fluvisol  (FLc)

[[3]]
        X.SITE COUNTRY    LAT     LONG      SCS Family
-99 Afganistan    34.5 69.167 Calcaric Fluvisol  (FLc)
# ------- now something that can pull them together ---------
do.call("rbind", lapply( Site_lines , function(L) read.table(text= tL, header=TRUE, skip=L-1, nrow=1) ) )

         X.SITE COUNTRY    LAT     LONG      SCS Family
-99  Afganistan    34.5 69.167    Luvic Calcisol  (CLl)
-991 Afganistan    34.5 69.000 Calcaric Fluvisol  (FLc)
-992 Afganistan    34.5 69.167 Calcaric Fluvisol  (FLc)
```

Unfortunately, that table is not a regular as might seem at first. If you look at the spacing of the "@SITE" positions in the full file (with its almost 60,000 lines) you get:

```
table(diff(Site_lines))

 10  12  14  16  18  20  22  24  26 
 47 156 526 664 797 906 169  85  53
```

And trying to use the  `lapply(` , ... `read.table` approach causes error. You may need to use a `for`-loop with `try`. The first error was at line 6070:

```
counter <- 0
do.call("rbind", lapply( Site_lines , function(L) { counter <<- L; read.table(text= tL, header=TRUE, skip=L-1, nrow=1) }))
Error in read.table(text = tL, header = TRUE, skip = L - 1, nrow = 1) : 
  more columns than column names
> counter
[1] 6070
```